# How to make TextBlock Height as big as how much text it's contains (xaml)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

How to make TextBlock height variable? Now it is 60.

```
<Border Background="{Binding ScreenBrush}" Margin="24,0" Width="800" MinHeight="60" local:Tilt.IsEnabled="True">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="{Binding TextSize}"
         Foreground="{Binding TextBrush}" Margin="12"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you specifically set the height property (or MaxHeight) it should expand when it needs to.  You haven't turned text wrapping on for the textblock so it will only use one line and expand horizontally.  To enable wrapping to mutliple lines use:

```
TextWrapping="Wrap"
```